# Are Evolutionary algorithms biotechnology?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

For my research project in biology for my final year I need to present a project in the field of Biotechnology. Being passionate about programming I immediately thought of Evolutionary Algorithms! However I am not sure if Evolutionary Algorithms would fall into the category of Biotechnology, hence I would rather confirm with the best and most passionate programming experts on the world.

Comment: Well, thank you! No. :P

Comment: I think the term of art for evolutionary algorithms and the others mentioned by @RBarryYoung is "Biologically Inspired Computing".

Comment: ... but then you realised that it would be easier to ask on Stack Overflow, instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Unfortunately no**, a genetic algorithm (ga) is just an optimization technique that is inspired from various evolutionary processes like mutation or crossover. They belong to the area of evolutionary computing and artificial intelligence and not biotechnology. 
Please follow [this](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/index.php) link for a brief introduction to genetic algorithms.

**Biotechnology** from the other hand has to do with actual organisms that are used in some way to make a product or an application. It sounds kind of broad but that is only because the particular field is in itself very broad. We use forms of biotechnology for thousands of years now in many common and not so common ways. This is not bad though as it gives you a lot of freedom regarding your project. Choose anything from food production to medicine and you will still be relevant to the subject. 
Maybe the links provided will give you some inspiration.

- [Link one](http://news.discovery.com/tech/dna-powered-nanotrain-builds-its-own-tracks-131111.htm)
- [Link two](http://www.organovo.com/3d-human-tissues/3d-human-tissues-research)

Answer (score 2):

Until you're implementing your evolutionary algorithms with organic material, **no**.

They are, of course, inspired from the way modern organisms have come to exist. But there's no biology in what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It's just an example of a biological algorithm adapted for computational purposes.

Other examples include Ant-Colony Optimization, Flocking behavior, etc.

IIRC, *Biotechnology* requires the use of actual biology (i.e., living things or parts of them) adapted for technological purposes, not just an algorithmic emulation or modelling of their processes.

Comment: Sigh, I was looking forward to do my finals on Evolutionary algorithms. Is there anything you could suggest to me? :)

Comment: @LukeTaylor Well, you might try something in [Bioinformatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics), that's probably about as close as you can come.  In particular, "Computational evolutionary biology" seems like it has some overlap.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I would check with your advisors though to make sure that's in-bounds for your subject area as it's close to the edge.

Comment: @LukeTaylor you could try searching for "using software to program biological cells", or "programmable DNA" or similar. E.g. see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/dna. This might qualify as biotechnology but I agree you'd need to check w/ your supervisors.